# Filtering Prefetch object using OuterRef and SubQuery

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

### Background

Let say I have this kind of structure:

#### models.py

```py
class Location(models.Model):
    pass

class Service(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name="services",on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Staff(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, related_name="staffs",on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Performance(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField("content", max_lenght=50)
    staff=models.ForeignKey(Staff, related_name="performances",on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def location(self):
       return self.staff.service.location
```

I want to expose my data through a rest API.

#### serializers.py

```py
class StaffSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Staff
        fields = ['id', 'service']


class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    staffs = StaffSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = ['id', 'staffs']


class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    services = ServiceSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ['id',]
```

#### Data structure

So... a serialized `Location` instance will look like:

```json
{
    "id":"some_location_id",
    "services":[
        {
            "id":"some_service",
            "staffs":[
                {"id":"some_staff_id"},
                {"id":"some_other_staff_id"}
            ]
        } // ... Repeated for each services
    ]
    
}
```

Now, for some reason, I need to expose `Performance` data through a scheme which looks like:

```json
{

    "id":"some_perfomance_id",
    "content":"Foo",
    "location":{
        "id":"performance_staff__service__location_id",
        "services":[
            {
                "id":"performance_staff__service_id",
                "staffs":[
                    {"id":"performance_staff_id"} // ... Only one staff!
                ]
            } // ... Only one service!
        ]
    }
}
```

### Investigated solutions

I did manage to make this work tweaking around `serializers` and passing data through
some private attributes, but I expect some really odd behaviors.

What I'm looking for is a way to do this using `Prefetch`

#### managers.py

Focusing "only" on `services` first, I'd expect something like this:

```py
class PerformanceManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        service_qs = SubQuery(
            Service.objects.filter(staffs=OuterRef("staff_id")).only("pk")
        )

        return super().get_queryset().prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                'staff__service__location__services',
                queryset=Services.objects.filter(pk__in=service_qs),
            )
        )
```

It looks like `Prefetch`, `SubQuery` and `OuterRef` are not playing well together, and that makes sense...
For one `location` instance, I want to setup multiple prefetched `services`, depending on which `performance` I access location...

### Interrogation

Is their any `pythonic` way to achieve this ?